# a long sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

Is this sentence weird?

> Many of the reviews of manuscript for publication I wrote during the PhD program have been highly evaluated by senior lab members and my advisor.

Couple of things underlying the sentence:
1. I wrote those reviews during my PhD program

1. They were reviews of manuscripts submitted for publication
2. Other senior lab members and my advisor (from the lab where I followed the PhD program) liked some of the reviews I wrote
3. It is for a formal email. Should I use laboratory instead? But I feel that will make the sentence even longer...

Comment: I think this is Off Topic proofreading. But fwiw I would add the word ***that*** after ***publication*** as an aid to clarity. Also I think ***highly evaluated*** sounds extremely "weird" - I'd use the more standard ***highly regarded***. As to ***lab/laboratory***, that's really a subjective issue - but if OP has any qualms, it certainly can't do any harm to use the full form.

Comment: Also, "manuscripts" or "a manuscript" depending on your context. And "my" PhD program. The sentence doesn't seem too long and is understandable.

Comment: Let me guess -you want to emphasize that what all you did has been noted as 'remarkable' by your seniors? If that's the case, I'd write it this way - *Many of my manuscript reviews I wrote for publication during my PhD **had been** evaluated **and were highly regarded** by the senior lab members and my adviser.*

Answer (score 3):

There are some minor errors of diction and idiom:

- *Reviews* is ambiguous, because at first encounter it may suggest published reviews; you might better say *assessments* or something similar.
- *Manuscripts for publication* go to the printer; what you probably mean is  *manuscripts submitted for publication*.
- *The PhD program* is the program offered by your department or laboratory; what you probably mean is *during my PhD studies*.
- *Have been highly evaluated by* would be better expressed as *received high evaluations from*, if in fact they were formally evaluated; if what you mean is merely that they were praised by senior lab members and your advisor, FumbleFingers' *were highly regarded by* is more appropriate.

But there are more important problems. First, your placement of modifying phrases and clauses is confusing. When I first read this I took it to mean that:

- During your PhD studies you wrote manuscript(s) for publication, and
- The reviews of these by senior lab members and your advisor gave your manuscripts high evaluations.

You have to be very careful when you pile up phrases this way.

Moreover, it is not at all clear what manuscripts you were reviewing, or for whom.

- Did your advisor and colleagues solicit your opinion of manuscripts they were planning to submit for publication? That itself is very strong evidence of how highly they valued your opinion.
- Or were you acting as reader for a journal? If the latter, for what journal?—that is, to my mind, more important (and impressive) than your colleagues’ opinions, unless they also constituted the journal’s editorial staff.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with what others have said; *highly evaluated* sounds stilted.

To make the language sound more natural (and to shorten the sentence a little), change *review* from a noun to a verb:

> Many of the manuscripts I wrote during my PhD program were reviewed favorably by my advisor and senior lab members.

I omitted "for publication," as that did not seem necessary. (The bullet merely indicates that you have the ability to write a good first draft, not get anything published.)

If the works were actually published, you should emphasize that fact, not the fact that your colleagues liked your initial work.